# Gutenberg editor scroll block into view

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reactjs, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

How can I scroll a newly inserted block into the view in the wordpress gutenberg editor?

I am creating the block with

```
const nextBlock = createBlock( 'core/paragraph' );
wp.data.dispatch( 'core/editor' ).insertBlock( nextBlock );
//scroll the block into the view
```

I have also seen that gutenberg uses the `dom-scroll-into-view` package like e.g. [here](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/7964f381e07e06b2ac13698fd1465a4d0c16da1b/packages/block-editor/src/components/inserter/menu.js#L18).

Their documentation says:

```
var scrollIntoView = require('dom-scroll-into-view');
scrollIntoView(source,container,config);
```

but how can I get it working in my case, how to get the source and container DOM elements?

Comment: Wonder if you could use `const blockNode = getBlockDOMNode( blockId )` and `const scrollContainer = getScrollContainer( blockNode )` as in [MultiSelectScrollIntoView](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/359858da0675943d8a759a0a7c03e7b3846536f5/packages/block-editor/src/components/multi-select-scroll-into-view/index.js). Maybe like `scrollIntoView( blockNode, scrollContainer, { onlyScrollIfNeeded: true, } );`
. Do we have the block Id from `nextBlock.id` or with the `'block-'` prefix ?

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle for this so we can reproduce your issue?

Comment: Well I guess not. Its the default wordpress installation with many wordpress specific js and css files. To reproduce, one would have to setup a wordpress environment with wordpress > 5.0 ... but maybe I will find a wordpress playground online somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in my case, how to get the source and container DOM elements?

It's actually quite easy.. just use `document.querySelector()` to get the block node and then `wp.dom.getScrollContainer()` to get that node's container:

```
const nextBlock = wp.blocks.createBlock( 'core/paragraph' );
wp.data.dispatch( 'core/editor' ).insertBlock( nextBlock );

const source = document.querySelector( '[data-block="' + nextBlock.clientId + '"]' );
const container = wp.dom.getScrollContainer( source );
```

References: [One](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/block-editor/src/components/multi-select-scroll-into-view/index.js#L37-L50) [Two](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/block-editor/src/utils/dom.js#L1)

And here's my code:

```
/**
 * External dependencies
 */
import scrollIntoView from 'dom-scroll-into-view';

/**
 * WordPress dependencies
 */
import { createBlock } from '@wordpress/blocks';     // wp.blocks.createBlock
import { dispatch } from '@wordpress/data';          // wp.data.dispatch
import { getScrollContainer } from '@wordpress/dom'; // wp.dom.getScrollContainer

function getBlockDOMNode( clientId ) {
    return document.querySelector( '[data-block="' + clientId + '"]' );
}

const nextBlock = createBlock( 'core/paragraph' );
dispatch( 'core/editor' ).insertBlock( nextBlock );

const source = getBlockDOMNode( nextBlock.clientId );
const container = source ? getScrollContainer( source ) : null;
if ( source && container ) {
    scrollIntoView( source, container );
}
```

### UPDATE

For testing the `import`ed `scrollIntoView()`, try this:

```
function scrollBlockIntoView( block ) {
    const source = getBlockDOMNode( block.clientId );
    const container = source ? getScrollContainer( source ) : null;
    if ( source && container ) {
        console.log( source, container );
        scrollIntoView( source, container );
    }
}

window.scrollBlockIntoView = function( block ) {
    scrollBlockIntoView( block || {} );
};
```

And then from the browser console, run this:

```
scrollBlockIntoView( wp.data.select('core/editor').getBlocks()[1] )
```

But make sure that you have at least two blocks in the editor — e.g. a paragraph with a lengthy content and an image block.

Tried and tested working on Chrome (Windows 10).

Comment: Is it working for you? Source and container are valid and seem to be the correct elements, but its not scrolling.

Comment: Your solution only works in safari, but I think the answer is complete and correct and closest to what I needed. Guess its a `dom-scroll-into-view` issue? Or might we using it wrong?

Comment: So I'm on WordPress 5.2.2. And actually, the `insertBlock()` call actually auto-scrolls the inserted block into view, without having to call `scrollIntoView()`. And yes, the `scrollIntoView()` in my code does work properly.

Answer (score 1):

`dom-scroll-into-view` is an NPM package by itself at https://github.com/yiminghe/dom-scroll-into-view

They have a demo available at http://yiminghe.me/dom-scroll-into-view/examples/demo.html

And their main source code is https://github.com/yiminghe/dom-scroll-into-view/blob/master/src/dom-scroll-into-view.js

---

Short answer:

- `source` is the HTML element you want to be brought into view.
- `container` is its container element, or you can simply put it to be `window` if you don't have a particular container wrapping your element.
- Finally `config` is an optional object that lets you configurate some fine tuning like a little bit of margin to top of left if you don't want this to hit the exact top border of the browser.  You can start by passing `{}` to it for now.

Comment: I know, but I cant figure that concrete usage in the case of gutenberg.

Comment: @niklas `scrollIntoView` needs DOM elements as it's a pure DOM action.  And React doesn't advise accessing DOM elements explicitly.  The only workaround is using `ref` which is exactly what the last guy who added `scrollIntoView` to gutenberg has done.  Here is the PR that you can follow: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/commit/9e2be1806501ff00ac628f8ec84344603451e164#diff-b35d15bd7807d4f198117c45c99c3443 . Basically, just add a ref to your created blocks, then get DOM using that ref and pass it to scrollIntoView.

Comment: and how to add refs to the "block editor container"?

Comment: @niklas you might be able to just leave it to be `window` and see how it works.  Otherwise, you can follow `this.inserterResults` in the PR I shared.